# How can I keep two element into one when the height is changeable?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Here is my HTML:

```css
.parent{
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 43%;
  width: 300px;
}

.first_el{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px; /* constant */
}

.second_el{
  border: 1px solild red;
  height: 100%; /* dynamic */
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="first_el">title</span>
  <div class="second_el">
    one<br>two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br> seven<br> eight<br>nine<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the second element is out of its parent. question is how can I set the whole of it into its parent for all screen-sizes?

Noted that I can use `calc(100%-30px)` as the `height` of `.second_el` and then the problem will be solved. But as i know `calc` for old browsers doesn't support `calc()`, Thus I don't want to use it. Is there any alternative? *(also I don't want to use `box-sizing: border-box;`, because of old browsers)*

Comment: If you really want to support ancient browsers, then you realise `position:fixed` is out too, right? By the way, you have a typo in the border-style of the `.second-el`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery for this to set the height programatically, and bind a handler on resize.

```
function setSecondChildHeight() {
  var BORDER_WIDTH = 1;
  var parentHeight = $('.parent').outerHeight();
  var firstChildHeight = $('.first_el').outerHeight();
  var secondChildHeight = parentHeight - firstChildHeight + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH;
  $('.second_el').height(secondChildHeight);
}

$(window).resize(setSecondChildHeight);

$(function() {
  setSecondChildHeight();  
});
```

Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15wam02w/

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. but I prfer to do that by pure CSS .. That's why I didn't attached JS tag to my question. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```css
.parent{
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 43%;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first_el{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px; /* same as class .parent padding-bottom */
  overflow:hidden;
}

.second_el{
  border: 1px solild red;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="first_el">title</span>
  <div class="second_el">
    one<br>two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br> seven<br> eight<br>nine<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The word of `nine` isn't visible in your snippet.

Comment: sorry,wait a moment

Comment: the answer also same as mine. lol i still waiting respond from stack what problem with my demo lol.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

add your parent class `overflow:hidden;`

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="first_el">title</span>
  <div class="second_el">
    one
    <br>two
    <br> three
    <br> four
    <br> five
    <br> six
    <br> seven
    <br> eight
    <br>nine
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 43%;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first_el{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.second_el{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dqk6tubj/)

Comment: Hi there, May i know why? is there wrong with the demo?

Comment: Hi .. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ezKHO.png) is what I'm seeing of your demo.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.second_el` border solid spell error is there. correct it and give `overflow-x:hidden` and `overflow-y: scroll`

```
.second_el{
  border: 1px soild red;
  height: 100%; /* dynamic */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Remove the border for `.parent` class to avoid merge border from `.second_el`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an `overflow:hidden;` in the parent div and see the magic !!

Like this

```css
.parent{
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 43%;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first_el{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 30px; /* constant */
}

.second_el{
  border: 1px solild red;
  height:80%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="first_el">title</span>
  <div class="second_el">
    one<br>two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br> seven<br> eight<br>nine<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aalind/qjyoo9wc/2/).